# How do I redirect to different home page when user is logged in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular9, behaviorsubject

I am trying to make a redirection to the `/dashboard` page whenever user is logged in.
The default landing page is `/home`, but logged in user home page is `/dashboard`.

I have a user service class where I create a sharedUser and it is BehaviorSubject:

```
  public sharedUser= new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
```

And then I have initUser method, where I give values to user object. `initUserStatus()` method is Observable and fills data from request.

```
private initUser(accessToken: string): void {
    const tokenData = TokenUtil.decodeToken(accessToken);

    this.user.email = tokenData.email;
    this.initUserStatus().subscribe(
      () => this.sharedUser.next(this.user)
    );
  }
```

And then I have Guard class where I try to redirect if user data is filled and is actually logged in:
User is logged in when email is initalized, `isLoggedIn()` method checks if there is email or not.

```
export class HomePageGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }

  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<UrlTree | boolean>  {
    return this.userService.sharedUser.asObservable().pipe(
      map(() => {
        if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) {
          return this.router.createUrlTree(['/dashboard']);
        }
        return true;
      }
    ));
  }
}
```

It seems that `canActivate` will be in endless loop and it won't go complete and thus it will not redirect to /dashboard page.

How can I fix that? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Instead of returning an observable, return boolean. and check if it still don't work.

Comment: Why specifically are you using createURLTree here

Comment: Change createUrlTree to navigate.

Comment: You can check the condition in the guard itself and navigate it to the respective route. Try if else directly.

Comment: @TomaszVizaint, the problem is not with the createUrlTree, the problem is that observable will never go to complete. I put console.log inside if-statement and browser went nuts. There must be way to when logging is finished and then check observable. Any idea?

Comment: @abhaytripathi where do you use boolean? In ``initUser``?

Comment: @avengerJoe9000 return boolean in guard. use whatever you want in inituser. although preferred way is Observable.

Comment: @abhaytripathi I returend boolean and it works, but when I add ``route.createUrlTree`` or ``route.navigate``, then it fails. starts to loop.

Comment: @avengerJoe9000 , I was suspecting the same. The reason is you seems to have misunderstood the observable thing. Can't say what by the given code.

Comment: Thaks for your time and suggestions. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable returned from a guard does not have to complete. Angular will use the [`first()` operator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/operators/check_guards.ts#L130) anyways.

```js
const canActivateObservables = canActivate.map((c: any) => {
    return defer(() => {
      const guard = getToken(c, futureARS, moduleInjector);
      let observable;
      if (isCanActivate(guard)) {
        observable = wrapIntoObservable(guard.canActivate(futureARS, futureRSS));
      } else if (isFunction<CanActivateFn>(guard)) {
        observable = wrapIntoObservable(guard(futureARS, futureRSS));
      } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid CanActivate guard');
      }
      return observable.pipe(first()); // 
    });
  });
```

What you could do in order to avoid the infinite loop is to check in your guard if the URL you're about to navigate to contains the `/dashboard` path. If that's the case, then you should not schedule a new navigation and return `true` instead.

```js
 map(() => {
  
  // or 
  // this.userService.isLoggedIn() && !route.url.some(({ path }) => path === 'dashboard')
  if (this.userService.isLoggedIn() && !state.url.includes('dashboard')) {
    return this.router.createUrlTree(['/dashboard']);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Strange. ``ths.router.createUrlTree`` will not navigate, instead it will start to loop. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: If any guard returns an UrlTree, it means _redirection_. So it will perform a new navigation based on the new UrlTree. You could log the guard’s arguments, it would be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by logging guard's arguments? How? I don't give any arguments to guard.

Comment: The arguments in this case are the ActivatedRouteSnapshot and RouterStateSnapshot, they are passed in when the guard is invoked by Angular. So this solution still doesn’t solve the problem? I’m pretty sure the answer can be found by logging those arguments

Comment: I managed to get it work by removing ``this.userService.isLoggedIn()``. If I refresh the page, user information is lost.